# @ngrx select specific slice of state from store when using a smart component recursively

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm kinda new to `ngrx` and I've encountered this little problem I haven't figured out how to solve yet.

Basically I have a `ListComponent` that renders an array of `ListItemComponent`s from a `ngrx` store.

```
@Component({ 
  ...
  template: `
    <list-item *ngFor="let item of item$ | async" [data]="item">
    </list-item>
  `
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  item$: Observable<ListItem>;
  constructor(private store: Store<ListState>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.item$ = this.store.select(selectListItems);
  }
}
```

Now, inside `ListItemComponent`, under some specific circumstances I want to render another `ListComponent` where I can add items to, however this doesn't work as I get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

My guess is, and correct me if I'm wrong, since the nested `ListComponent` is accessing the same slice of state as the root `ListComponent`, its just trying to nest and render the same list over and over and over again into infinity.

So here's the question, how should I compose my selectors in order to provide the correct entry point in the state tree to each nested `ListComponent`?

---

#### Edit

Here's a [working stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-recursive-components), now the logic in my app to render a `List` inside a `ListItem` is different but the problem is the same.

Comment: u just need to pass `selectListItems` as `Input` in `ListComponent`

Comment: care to elaborate how that would solve my issue? I mean, in order to pass the function as input, should I that make my `ListStepComponent` store aware as well?

Comment: can u pls post the code for `selectListItems` and `ListStepComponent` ?

Comment: Yes,  give me some time to reproduce the example in stackblitz

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: 1 control data with app component - smart component , 2 assign items as an @Input, 3. change  state to a tree structure like items:[{name:'item1',items:[]},{name:'item2',items:[]}]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right:

> My guess is, and correct me if I'm wrong, since the nested ListComponent is accessing the same slice of state as the root ListComponent, its just trying to nest and render the same list over and over and over again into infinity.

Try updating `ListComponent` to accept a component input variable of `ListItemComponent`. See working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-recursive-components-7mzncj

In that example, the 5th `ListItemComponent` also renders a `ListComponent`. However, when clicking the "add element to list" button on that 5th ListItemComponent, the code is still adding the new elements to the parent list. I'm guessing you'll want to update your logic for how that is handled. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

The core problem is that the list is generating itself. So if a list generates another list, you run into the recursive problem. By using component input variables, you can stop the list from generating itself and eliminate the recursive problem.

#### Update:

I came to this answer on my own, but I just noticed that @FanCheung, in the comments, previously proposed what is basically this solution.

Comment: Yeah, after reading @FanCheung comment I basically came to the same solution as you're providing. The problem now is adding the new generated list item in the corresponding child list. I think I should update the reducer to iterate through the whole tree, find the correct node from where the action was dispatched, (perhaps with some unique id?)  and return the state... the problem i see with that approach is, since the selector is selecting the root list, whenever I add a nested step, it's gonna update the whole state tree, whilst I'd prefer the selector to only affect the corresponding branch

Comment: @OsmanCea actually I don't think you need to worry about updating the whole state tree (at least performance wise). If you push out a new state tree, but only a bit of it has changed, I think angular is smart enough to _only_ update those pieces of the DOM that have actually changed. Ya, there will be a bit of overhead as angular looks at the diffs, but I think it will be negligible (unless your lists are REALLY large, I suppose).

Comment: As an example, if you subscribe to a list in the store and then something is appended to the list, your subscription will receive a whole new copy of the list. Angular is smart enough to _only_ actually add the new item on the end though. If your list items are each rendered by their own component, you could test this by `console.log` during `ngOnChanges`. When you append something to the list you'll notice the existing list elements won't run their `OnChanges`. The only diff is adding a new element. Angular is very smart :)

Comment: since no one else cared to give me an answer, you get the bounty ;)

Comment: I did solved my problem though (it implied generating some unique id's for every list component, getting a path of a given id, and doing some deep state update immutable stuff but hey, it was worth it)

Comment: @OsmanCea, sounds like you've already put in the work, but I just read about angular's `ngFor` `trackBy` option that lets you tell angular how to determine if items in a list of actually changed. In this article, [`Tip 3: Minimize DOM Manipulations`](https://blog.angular.io/3-tips-for-angular-runtime-performance-from-the-real-world-d467fbc8f66e) explains more.